# Gradle : why this build.gradle.kts script fails to produce any java class?

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, compilation

Below is a *build.gradle.kts* script which applies to kotlin code located at `src/main/kotlin`.

It is an attempt of the translation from a groovy script which runs correctly.

The *gradlew build* steps has no error, but fails to produce any java *class* from the kotlin code. What instruction is missing ?

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath(kotlin("gradle-plugin", version = "1.2.70"))   
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.70")
        classpath("com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.20.0")
    }
}

plugins {
    jacoco
    java
    application
    "com.github.ben-manes.versions"
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

jacoco {
 toolVersion = "0.8.1"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.70")
    implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.4.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0")

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.12")
    testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-core:2.12.0")
    testImplementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.11.0")
    testImplementation("org.assertj:assertj-core:3.10.0")
}

application {
    mainClassName = "io.ipfs.kotlin.MainKt"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've added the Kotlin plugin to the build script here:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath(kotlin("gradle-plugin", version = "1.2.70"))   
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.70")
        classpath("com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.20.0")
    }
}
```

**but you have not applied it**

```
plugins {
    jacoco
    java
    application
    "com.github.ben-manes.versions"
    // No kotlin plugin actually applied here!
}
```

Actually, `buildscript` Kotlin configuration is not needed, as the Kotlin plugin is published to the Gradle's plugins directory. So you can just apply it as simple as:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm").version("1.2.70")
}
```